# Converting an int to a Char c#?

Tags: c#, input, char

I want to be able to Read a value from the operator M/F for male or female and return seperate blocks of text for each respective entry.

```
Char gender;
int TempValue;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
Console.CursorVisible=true;
String name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(" Greetings, faire travler {0} you are about to depart on a rather exciting adventure, but first are you male or female?", name);
Console.WriteLine("(M/F)");

TempValue = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", TempValue);
gender = Char.Parse(TempValue);
```

Now i get an error saying I "cannot convert from 'INT' to 'string' which I really dont understand. Becuase im trying to parse it into a char not a string.

Comment: Shouldn't that be gender = Char.Parse(TempValue); ? or you could simply do gender = (char)TempValue;

Comment: same error either way

Comment: You are reading (TempValue = Console.Read();) and specifying (M/F) so how does this put an int into TempValue? Which you then try to convert to a char.

Comment: Consider searching first for help if you don't know what particular method does - i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Console.Read - gives you explanation and sample of what you are looking for in first link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: the command console.Read in c# only returns Int values

Comment: If i tell it to return the value entered it will give me the ascII number for the value entered

Comment: Then try Console.WriteLine("(char)122 is {0}", (char)122); Like i said earlier use gender = (char)TempValue;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.Read()` returns the ascii value of the character you entered. (In case of 'M' it's 77)
`char.Parse(TempValue)` expects `TempValue` to be a `string` and that it contains exactly one character. So, this is what you would use to convert the string "M" to the character 'M'. But you don't have the string "M"; you have the int 77.
In this case, you can simply cast it:

```
char gender = (char)TempValue;
```

Alternatively, you can use `Console.ReadLine()`, which returns a `string` and then take the first character:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char gender = input[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`Char.Parse` takes a `string` as it's parameter, but `TempValue` is declared as an `int`. You can either `ToString` `TempValue`:

```
gender = Char.Parse(TempValue.ToString());
```

or use `Convert.ToChar()`, which takes an `object`:

```
gender = Convert.ToChar(TempValue);
```

Comment: Ok thanks that cleared up my issue. but the formatting is kind of clunky. is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean clunky? You can also cast it, like `gender = (char)TempValue;`